# Ler coluna do phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

Consegui separar alguns valores de uma coluna em uma tabela no PhpMyAdmin através de algumas dicas e fiz isso:

```php
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
if ($dep != ""  and $sub != "") {
    $query_rsPesquisa = "SELECT * FROM  `produtos` WHERE id_departamento = $dep AND id_subdepartamento = $sub";
} else {
    $query_rsPesquisa = "SELECT * FROM  `produtos` WHERE id_departamento = $dep";
}
$rsPesquisa = mysql_query($query_rsPesquisa, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa);
$totalRows_rsPesquisa = mysql_num_rows($rsPesquisa);

$string = $row_rsPesquisa['id_subfiltro'];  
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

E depois, para buscar a descrição de cada *id* em uma tabela específica e mostrar em minha página, fiz isso:

```php
<?php

if ($dep != "" and $sub != "") {
    foreach ($array as $valores) {

        mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
        $query_rsSub = "SELECT * FROM subfiltro WHERE id_subfiltro = $valores";
        $rsSub = mysql_query($query_rsSub, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rsSub       = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSub);
        $totalRows_rsSub = mysql_num_rows($rsSub);

        $descProd = $row_rsSub['descricao'];

        echo "<ul class='menu2'>
                    <li><a href='#'>$descProd</a></li>
                    <li class='current-menu-item'></li>                
                  </ul>";            
    }
}
?>
```

Mas o que é estranho é que o meu primeiro `select` não está pegando todos os valores de minha coluna *id_subfiltro*, parece que para no primeiro, vejam a imagem a seguir:

[image: Tabela]

A página é essa: [Página em desenvolvimento](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1&sub=4)

Os valores que, nesse caso preciso resgatar seria *8,2,61,155,6,17,16,176,117*.

Mas está me retornando isso:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 2 [2] => 61 [3] => 155 [4] => 6 [5] => 17 )
```

Comment: Rodando essa consulta no phpMyAdmin, o valor dessa coluna também fica cortado?

Comment: Olá @Lucas, não, o resultado aparece completo.

Comment: Ao meu ver, ja resolveu certo? Poste aqui a resolução.

Comment: Olá Lollipop, consegui resolver sim, mas ainda tenho algumas dúvidas que precisam ser devidamente sanadas.

Comment: Apenas uma dica: funções mysql_* estão obsoletas a desde o PHP 5.5. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O grande problema que estava tendo era que não estava conseguindo armazenar os registros depois de usar o explode, como estive muito tempo realizando teste nessa página acabei que esquecendo de fazer um loop para varrer as opções e armazena-las de forma correta.
A solução que encontrei foi simples, vejam só:

```
    // defini a variável como array
    $subGrupos = array();

    do {

        $string = $row_rsPesquisa['id_subfiltro'];
        // separei os registros por vírgula     
        $array = explode(',', $string); 
        // uni a variável $subGrupo com o array
        $subGrupos = array_merge($subGrupos, $array);   

    } while ($row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa));

    // desconsiderei os valores repetidos.
    $array = array_unique($subGrupos);
```

Eis o código, agradeço a todos que me ajudaram nos comentários.